# Cauchy theorem in a general domain

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f$ be an analytic function in $D$ and continuous on $\partial D$, where $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is an open set, bounded by a Jordan curve.

Is it true that $f\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits _{\partial D}\frac{f\left(\xi\right)}{\xi-z}d\xi$?

I know how to prove it for a *disk* D, using uniform continuity of $\frac{f\left(\xi\right)\cdot\xi}{\xi-z}$, and perhaps if it is half a circle with a straight line connecting the edges, but it seems to fail when $D$ is any open set.

[EDIT 1: Refined the boundary to be bounded by a Jordan curve]
[EDIT 2: Refined terms]

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the integration is performed on a contour $\gamma$ that encloses the set?

Comment: $f$ need not be defined on that contour.

Comment: It is continuous there, hence defined?

Comment: A contour that encloses $D$ is not contained in $D$. $f$ is only defined and continuous on $\overline D$

Comment: I have refined my question. I meant that $f$ is analytic inside $D$, but on the boundary it is only continuous.

Comment: $\partial D$ needs to be rectifiable for the integral to make sense and then the result is true  (a straightforward proof uses Riemann mapping theorem and the fact that any Riemann map from the unit disc extends continuously and injectively to the boundary in the Jordan curve boundary case with the extension absolutely continuous if the respective Jordan curve is rectifiable)

Comment: @Conrad Thank you! Can you elaborate a bit more, though?

Answer (score 0):

An outline of the above comment explicited:

Let $U$ a domain bounded by a rectifiable Jordan curve $J$; then $U$ is simply connected so we can pick $\phi$ a Riemann map from the unit disc $\mathbb D$ to $U$; then Caratheodory theorem says that $\phi$ extends to a continuous (bijective) map from the unit circle $C$ to $J$, call it still $\phi$, and a corollary of the Riesz brothers theorem on analytic measures says that $J$ is rectifiable if and only if $\phi$ is absolutely continuous on $C$ (or equivalently $\phi' \in H^1$) and then $\phi$ gives a change of variables on the boundary hence $$\int_J \frac {f(\zeta)d\zeta}{z-\zeta}=\int_C  \frac {f(\phi(\eta))\phi'(\eta)d\eta}{\phi (w)-\phi(\eta)}, z=\phi(w)$$ and by the usual Cauchy (or residue theorem if you prefer as the integrand has a pole at $w$ with residue $f(\phi(w))$) $$\int_C  \frac {f(\phi(\eta))\phi'(\eta)d\eta}{\phi (w)-\phi(\eta)}=2\pi i f(\phi(w))=2\pi if(z)$$